# how to display current time as a static value in lua/pico8

Tags: lua, pico-8

Pico8 has a function time() that when called displays the current time from start of program.
i.e. print(time(),0,0,14) --prints time at (0,0) with colour 14

However the function doesn't stop and keeps drawing the time each frame. I'm trying to figure out how I would draw the time without it increasing/changing. So If I printed this 5 seconds from the start of the program I'd want it to display 5, but not change from that 5 value.

https://pico-8.fandom.com/wiki/Time
I don't know how to store a static value of this time as a variable. Although according to the wiki, assigning  var=time() will cause time at 0 to be stored.

Another way of phrasing this is...how would I display the time of 10 seconds when the following print is triggered? So after 10 seconds "time's up" is displayed. How would I display the current time 10, as well, as a static? Maybe I don't know what the time is when the event is triggered, so how can I count using time()?

```
function _init()
  last = time()
end

function _update()
  -- (empty update to use game loop)
end

function _draw()
  cls()
  if (time() - last) > 10 then
    print("time's up!", 44, 60, 7)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you should be able to initialize a variable at 0, then on the callback you can check if it is 0, and if it is, set the time. *I am not entirely familiar with Lua.*

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correctly by setting `time()` at a certain point as your own static variable.

Things you should know:

- `time()` can be abbreviated to `t()`
- `time()` is recorded as a float (a decimal) of seconds to ten-thousandths of a second.

To print what time your timer went off, first re-set your `LAST` variable to be the current time within your timer `IF` statement.

Then outside and after your timer `IF` statement, print the `LAST` variable.

```
function _init()
  last = time()
end

function _update()
  -- (empty update to use game loop)
end

function _draw()
  cls()
  if (time() - last) > 10 then
    print("time's up!", 44, 60, 7)
    last=time()
  end
  print(last, 44, 70)
end
```

If you don't want to print the time as a decimal and instead show only the seconds, then you can use the function `flr()` to round down like this:

```
  print(flr(last), 44, 70)
```

> NOTICE: The only problem with this code, is that `"TIME'S UP!"` will only flash on the screen because I reset `last` to the current time. So the timer resets and flashes every 10 seconds and updates the static time variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve, but maybe something like this?

```lua
local start
local limit = 10
local finish

function _init()
  start = time()
end

function _draw()
  cls()
  local now = time()
  local delta = now - start
  if delta >= limit then
    -- time's up
    print("time's up!", 44, 60, 7)
    -- saving timestamp
    if finish == nil then
      finish = now
    end
  else
    -- still ticking
    print(delta, 44, 60, 7)
  end
end
```